# Is there a less verbose way to write DynamoDB update params?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, mongoose, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to Dynamo and I created a [simple todo API](https://github.com/LuisEnMarroquin/todolist-serverless/blob/main/src/todos.ts) with Serverless Framework and TypeScript

To update an Item I have to do this huge `params` const

```
const params = {
  TableName: process.env.DYNAMO_TABLE_TODO,
  Key: {
    id: event.pathParameters.id,
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#todo_text": "text",
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":text": data.text,
    ":checked": data.checked,
    ":updatedAt": timestamp,
  },
  UpdateExpression: "SET #todo_text = :text, checked = :checked, updatedAt = :updatedAt",
  ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
}

// update the todo in the database
dynamoDb.update(params, (error, result) => {
  if (error) throw error

  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(result.Attributes),
  })
})
```

Is there a more cleaner way to do this? With Mongoose I will simply do

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({{ _id: id }, {
  text: data.text,
  checked: data.checked,
  updatedAt: timestamp
})
```

It's not only about code being ugly or not, if I want a property A2 be written to the database only if A1 is present in Mongoose I can just remove that property from the second object, while in Dynamo I would have to write a different `ExpressionAttributeValues` and `UpdateExpression` adding more probabilities of me or other dev making an error

Comment: I do not necessarily recommend going with the answer I posted. DynamoDB is different, and it might help to be a bit more verbose. Since you're using typescript I would advise to go with the latest sdk: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referring to Mongoose which is an abstraction, it's only fair to answer the question by providing a similar abstraction.

There's a modelling tool inspired by mongoose which should provide what you're asking for.
https://github.com/dynamoose/dynamoose

This will allow you to do stuff like this:

```
await User.update({"id": 1, "name": "Bob"}); // This code will set `name` to Bob for the user where `id` = 1
```

from https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Model#modelupdatekey-updateobj-settings-callback